# Excel formula if ref# on table b is found one or many times on ref# on table a

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got requirement to look over [Table A with 15k lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EduHr.png) where there's duplicate Ref#s and return "FOUND" if that ref# is listed in Table B.

[Table B is a unique list of 100 Ref#s and there are no duplicates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l75TF.png)

I've tried a few functions but the only one I can wrap my head around without stringing too many functions is xlookup. Here's my attempt;

```
=XLOOKUP([@ReferenceNumber],SALES_ORDERS[@[Sales Orders]],SALES_ORDERS[@[Sales Orders]],"N/A")
```

but I'm receiving a #value error which doesn't make sense to me as all of the comparing fields are text data type and in tables. I thought about using it nonetheless but I've found that it's accuracy is poor or incorrect so it does me no good.

Could someone assist me with this excel function?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was able to create with excel formula...

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH([@ReferenceNumber],SALES_ORDERS[Sales Orders],0)),"N/A","FOUND")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first XLOOKUP formula is the @ in the 2nd and 3rd arguments.

The @ sign indicates you only want to look at the current row of a column. That's what you want for the first argument (you're just looking up one row at a time), but not for the 2nd and 3rd arguments (you want to search the entire columns, not just a single row).

The below should have worked as you intended:

```
=XLOOKUP([@ReferenceNumber],SALES_ORDERS[Sales Orders],SALES_ORDERS[Sales Orders],"N/A")
```